# JSON.parse unexpected token s

Tags: javascript, json

Why is it that whenever I do :-

```
JSON.parse('"something"')
```

it just parses fine but when I do:-

```
var m = "something";
JSON.parse(m);
```

it gives me an error saying:-

```
Unexpected token s
```

Comment: "something" is not valid JSON (it doesn't include the quotes).

Comment: @SLaks parse it like normal string but from all the responses string literal is not a valid JSONstring.

Comment: It's a string already.  There isn't anything to parse.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You're asking it to parse the JSON text `something` (not `"something"`). That's invalid JSON, strings must be in double quotes.

If you want an equivalent to your first example:

```
var s = '"something"';
var result = JSON.parse(s);
```

Comment: that works - but I thought that JS allowed single and double quotes without prejudice.  Good to know though.

Comment: @reabow: JavaScript allows single or double quotes. JSON does not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, JSON is pretty particular, especially after you are used to python dicts - maybe it should be called Just Someother Object Notation then :)

Answer (score 20):

What you are passing to JSON.parse method must be a valid JSON after removing the wrapping quotes for string.

so `something` is not a valid JSON but `"something"` is.

A valid JSON is -

```
JSON = null
    /* boolean literal */
    or true or false
    /* A JavaScript Number Leading zeroes are prohibited; a decimal point must be followed by at least one digit.*/
    or JSONNumber
    /* Only a limited sets of characters may be escaped; certain control characters are prohibited; the Unicode line separator (U+2028) and paragraph separator (U+2029) characters are permitted; strings must be double-quoted.*/
    or JSONString

    /* Property names must be double-quoted strings; trailing commas are forbidden. */
    or JSONObject
    or JSONArray
```

Examples -

```
JSON.parse('{}'); // {}
JSON.parse('true'); // true
JSON.parse('"foo"'); // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null'); // null 
JSON.parse("'foo'"); // error since string should be wrapped by double quotes
```

You may want to look [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 7):

Variables (`something`) are not valid JSON, verify using http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4):

valid json string must have double quote.

```
JSON.parse({"u1":1000,"u2":1100})       // will be ok
```

no quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({u1:1000,u2:1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

single quote cause error

```
JSON.parse({'u1':1000,'u2':1100})    
// error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2
```

You must valid json string at [https://jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Because JSON has a string data type (which is practically anything between `"` and `"`). It does not have a data type that matches `something`