# Invalid JSON,Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to send JSON data to server using angular, But getting JSON.parse error in firefox and Unexpected token in chrome.

It works sometime and throws error sometime.

I consider it is because of the timestamp I'm using to create some keys.

```
{
    "genericformfieldId": "1",
    "userId": "2",
    "formData": {
        "_1443551400000": [
            {
                "mValue": "HARYANA",
                "type": "DropDown",
                "name": "selectState"
            }
        ],
        "_1443637800000": [
            {
                "mValue": "CHHATTISGARH",
                "type": "DropDown",
                "name": "selectState"
            }
        ],
        "_1443810600000": [
            {
                "mValue": "sac",
                "type": "SingleLineText",
                "name": "departureFrom"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Adding code for posting data

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:    Url, 
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, 
    data: formData
    })
.success( function( response, status, headers, config ) {
    console.log( response );
    if( response ) {                    
        deferred.resolve( response );
    }
})
.error( function( response, status, headers, config ) {  
    deferred.reject( null );
});
```

Comment: This is a valid JSON string.

Comment: Ths JSON is always this? Because this is a valid JSON, probably in some cases you are sending an invalid one,

Comment: Refer to this question, May be it would be helpful to you.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791718/json-parse-unexpected-token-s

Comment: This is valid JSON. can you please put exact error. Parse errors generally comes when you don't put quotes around key or property. like if you use mValue instead of "mValue".

Comment: @irvin .. No JSON is created dynamically...

Comment: @murli2308 I will try to get more test cases.

Comment: @zion can you post an example of the invalid one? And the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but if you want to send a JSON to the server - why do you use JSON.parse?? Shouldn't you use JSON.stringify?

Comment: sorry for a late response.. there seems to be no issue with the data.. May be with the code..

Comment: @Michael I will try using that..

Comment: @Michael It didn't worked..either

Comment: use ` (backtick) for wrapping all this is in a multiline string

Comment: Look, maybe this is the answer for your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211443/change-content-type-to-application-json-post-method-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

If you JSON.parse an object the "Unexpected token o" is thrown simply because you are trying to parse `object.toString()`, which is [object Object]. Try to `JSON.parse('[object Object]'); ;)`

This should work for you

```
var data = '{
    "genericformfieldId": "1",
    "userId": "2",
    "formData": {
        "_1443551400000": [
            {
                "mValue": "HARYANA",
                "type": "DropDown",
                "name": "selectState"
            }
        ],
        "_1443637800000": [
            {
                "mValue": "CHHATTISGARH",
                "type": "DropDown",
                "name": "selectState"
            }
        ],
        "_1443810600000": [
            {
                "mValue": "sac",
                "type": "SingleLineText",
                "name": "departureFrom"
            }
        ]
    }
}';
JSON.parse(data);
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719860/1868660 explains 
`Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)` issue

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)

Comment: use ` (backticks) for multiline strings

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719860/1868660 explains  Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…) issue

Answer (score 0):

You must clean input json.

Check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/am190cv5/

Here's the source:

```
var s = '{"genericformfieldId": "1","userId": "2","formData": {"_1443551400000": [{"mValue": "HARYANA","type": "DropDown","name": "selectState"}],"_1443637800000": [{"mValue": "CHHATTISGARH","type": "DropDown","name": "selectState"}],"_1443810600000": [{"mValue": "sac","type": "SingleLineText","name": "departureFrom"}]}}';

var result = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(result);
```

Open the console and look the result.

Comment: "clean"? What does it exactly mean?

Comment: I mean unformatted - without \r\n. In this case it works correctly: var result = JSON.parse(s); console.log(result);

Comment: It would work even with new lines. New lines is a valid JSON character.