# JSON result not displaying selected events from the fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I have an HTML select box which allows the admin to select the events based on the teacher selected

```
      <select id="teachermale" name="teachermale">
        <option selected disabled>Male Teachers</option>
        <option value="Mohamed Adil">Mohamed Adil</option>
        <option value="Sherif Reda">Sherif Reda</option> 
        <option value="Mohamed Shahban">Mohamed Shahban</option> 
        <option value="Abdullah al Haiti">Abdullah al Haiti</option>
        <option value="Salah">Salah</option>
        <option value="Ahmed Nabil">Ahmed Nabil</option>  
        <option value="Abdul Tawab">Abdul Tawab</option>
        <option value="Mahmoud Mahmoud">Mahmoud Mahmoud</option>  
        <option value="Ahmed Ghanim">Ahmed Ghanim</option>
      </select>
```

And the following jquery removes all current events from the jquery fullcalendar to display the specific teacher's events. And an ajax request is established to fetch the events for the respective teacher from the database.

```
      $(function() {
        $("#teachermale").change(function(){
                  var str = "";
                   $("#teachermale option:selected").each(function(){
                      str += $(this).text() + "";  
                  });

                  console.log(str);
                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                  changeDisplay(str);


               }).change();

      }); 
      function changeDisplay(str){
        console.log(str);
         $.ajax({
                 url:'find_event.php',
                 type:'POST',
                 data : '&str='+encodeURIComponent(str),
                 dataType:'text',
                 success: function(json) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);
                 },
                 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText); 
                 }
          });

       }
```

The POST is working and the specific teachers' events are being fetched correctly in JSON.

And the following is the find_event.php script which gets the events.

```
            // List of events
            $json_array["title"]=$_POST["str"];
            $title =$json_array["title"];
            echo $title;

            // connection to the database
            try{

                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*******', '******', '*******');
                } catch(Exception $e) {

                exit('Unable to connect to database.');
            }

            $requete = "SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE `title`=?";
            // Prepare your query
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($requete);
            if ($stmt) {
                if ($stmt->execute(array($title))) {
                    $events = array();
                    $dbEvents = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($dbEvents as $event) {
                        $event['allDay'] = false;
                        $events[] = $event;
                    }
                } else {
                    // check for error
                    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
                }
            }

            echo json_encode($events);
```

The console logs the string(i.e title) and at the Network tab shows that the str was posted. But I can't seem to get the calendar to display it on the screen even though I am using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);` to get back the events from the json source on success.

Any inputs on how to check this or how to get the events to display would be appreciated.

Json response when a console.log is done on it :
 `Salah[{"id":"24","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-02 10:00:00","end":"2016-06-02 14:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":null},{"id":"26","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-23 08:30:00","end":"2016-06-23 11:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":"green"}]`

Here is how the request headers look like.

[image]

Comment: The URL in the GET request in your screenshot looks definitely wrong. Also, what' in the json variable that is passed to addEventSource? Can you show an example?

Comment: Do I see clearly `type:'POST',` in code ?

Comment: @K48 How can I show you the json variable ? Any advice ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes, there is Post in the code !

Answer (score 0):

In the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);` code, you can send the 2nd argument as the URL as well. If that is given as a URL, it will initiate an Ajax call by itself. So you could write it as:

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'find_event.php?str=' + +encodeURIComponent(str) );
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');`

Once you do the above, you will need to fetch the data in find_event.php with $_GET instead of $_POST.

Alternatively, you could simply add this line below your `addEventSource` code, so it looks like:

`success: function(json) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');
},`

We have a working fullcalendar installation with Ajax filters using the above way (1st one).

**Solution**:

Your current function is initiating one more ajax call after find_event.php call:

```
function changeDisplay(str){
console.log(str);
     $.ajax({
             url:'find_event.php',
             type:'POST',
             data : '&str='+encodeURIComponent(str),
             dataType:'text',
             success: function(json) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);
             },
             error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText); 
             }
      });
   }`
```

This is what happens in the console: http://screencast.com/t/gUUconTtK .

You can change your function to:

```
function changeDisplay(str){
    console.log(str);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'find_event.php?str=' + encodeURIComponent(str));
}
```

This ensures that only one call is made & the events are populated from the file onto the calendar. With the above function, this is how my JSON output looks like: http://screencast.com/t/l3H2pJguM . And this is how my calendar appears after selecting a value from the dropdown: http://screencast.com/t/oWrd4bj5pV .

With your function as it is, although I see my events correctly in the JSON response, but the calendar shows blank.

Please note that what I am showing are test events.

Comment: You mean I do not perform the ajax post at all and just pass the url as 2nd parameter ?

Comment: The `refetchEvents` gets back all the events but when I select a teacher named `Salah` on drop down selection this is what I get  in the console:
`jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/MarkazAlIsbaah/calendar/Salah[%7B%22id%22:%2224%22,%22titl…22color%22:%22green%22%7D]?start=2016-05-29&end=2016-07-10&_=1468208226255 400 (Bad Request)`

And I am supposed to get events for this teacher specifically and not all of them.

Comment: Yes @UmarAftab. Remove the ajax call & instead only pass the url as second parameter in the `addEventSource` line.

Comment: Let me try this out and get back !

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
`/find_event.php?str=NaN&start=2016-05-29&end=2016-07-10&_=1468210245232`

Comment: The `str` is the name of the teacher. Any ideas how to get this going ?

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(str);` in the `changeDisplay()`?

Comment: There were 2 of these `+` and there was an ampersand before str missing `&`.
After adding them this is what I get in the Network tab :

`Request URL:http://localhost/MarkazAlIsbaah/calendar/find_event.php?&str=Salah&start=2016-05-29&end=2016-07-10&_=1468210795522`

`Request Method:GET`

`Status Code:500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: This is what I get :
`/Mohamed%20AdilArray(%20%20%20%20[0…false,%22color%22:null%7D]?start=2016-06-26&end=2016-08-07&_=1468230112175 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Please get rid of the `echo $title;` line in your find_event.php file. Because of that title being echoed, although the valid response is being returned back, it won't consider it as JSON response because that $title is not part of your JSON object.

Comment: @UmarAftab I have just updated my answer with a working solution.

Comment: I still get a blank calendar with your suggested solution.
`jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/MarkazAlIsbaah/calendar/find_event.php?str=Salah&start=2016-05-29&end=2016-07-10&_=1468255225115 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Ok. I assume if there is 500 error, then that means you aren't getting any JSON response back.
In that case, first remove your MySQL queries & try to send static JSON output back which has some events.
If that gets populated fine, then next try to send events from your MySQL table back as the response (without any WHERE conditions in the query). 
And if that works, then evaluate your MySQL query & see if it matches any result sets or not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the `str` variable from your code.

In `$("#teachermale").change()`, you create the `str` variable by a loop on each options selected and get it's text.

`str` wich is now an "aggregation" of selected names (Without delimiters, btw... so it will look like *"Sherif RedaMohamed ShahbanAbdul TawabAhmed Ghanim"*) is then passed to `changeDisplay(str)`

It is "considered" as an `encodeURIComponent` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) value and sent as `$_POST[data]` to `find_event.php`.

Your question is really strange when pretending you console log is the right related error.
.oO(I think not)
Because the address doesn't fit the code shown (str variable)... and the method doesn't fit either.

And why do you trigger a `change` chained with a change handler ?

Related to your posted code, you should look for a console status of a POST on url `find_event.php`.
It looks like there is more than one problem in your scripts.
;/
Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: str is not aggregated, it is just the selected option from the selectbox. Its just a single string

Comment: Yes. The term "aggregated" was not the right technical word. STILL, You now have a name string looking like what I wrote. NOT a GET part of an address. So, I maintain my point.

Comment: So whats your solution to it ?

Comment: Is the page freezes because of the GET error 400? If no, do you have a `$_POST['str']` recieived and echoed (if you test it) in `find_event.php` ?

Comment: The JSON returned in the success function is as follows:-
 `Salah[{"id":"24","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-02 10:00:00","end":"2016-06-02 14:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":null},{"id":"26","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-23 08:30:00","end":"2016-06-23 11:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":"green"}]`

I did a `console.log(json)` in the success function.

Comment: This is the error I am getting preventing the events from showing up on the calendar :
`/Mohamed%20AdilArray(%20%20%20%20[0…false,%22color%22:null%7D]?start=2016-06-26&end=2016-08-07&_=1468230112175 400 (Bad Request)`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Jquery [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) like so:

```
success: function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);
}
```

Comment: That was helpful David, because now I have a descriptive error.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 17`

Comment: try using `print_r($events);` just before `echo json_encode($events);` to debug the error

Comment: The events are printing in an array format in the console.log() but they are not being displayed on the calendar.

Comment: Here is the error I am dealing with :
`/Mohamed%20AdilArray(%20%20%20%20[0…false,%22color%22:null%7D]?start=2016-06-26&end=2016-08-07&_=1468230112175 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Try using `$event['allDay'] = "false";` in your php file. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791718/json-parse-unexpected-token-s) is link to a similar question with your error message. Hope this helps.