# unexpected 's' in postman on sending Webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax, stripe-payments, webmethod, postman

Integrating a payment Checkout `Stripe`. 
Used JavaScript Stripe handler, to apply Stripe charge on the transaction.
After charging the customer, it returns **token**. Using this token we can proceed for Actual payment.

And here is the AJAX call to *Payment functionality*:

```
var StripeHelper =
    {
        payProceed: function (token) {
            try {
                var _ajax = new AjaxHelper("/Services/Service.asmx/PaymentProceed");
                _ajax.Data = "{token:" + JSON.stringify(token) + "}";
                _ajax.OnInit = function () { PageHelper.loading(true); };
                _ajax.OnSuccess = function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d);
                    PageHelper.loading(false);
                    window.location('/payment-success');
                };
                _ajax.Init();
            }
            catch (e) {
                PageHelper.loading(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Web Method on my **TEST server**, which passes token to Stripe server:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string PaymentProceed(string token)
    {
        Session["PAYMENT_MODE"] = PaymentContants.PaymentVia.Stripe;
        var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();
        myCharge.AmountInCents = 100;
        myCharge.Currency = "USD";
        myCharge.Description = "Charge for property sign and postage";
        myCharge.TokenId = token;
        string key = "sk_test_Uvk2cH***********Fvs"; //test key

        var chargeService = new StripeChargeService(key);
        StripeCharge stripeCharge = new StripeCharge();
        //Error is coming for below line -->
        stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
        //No token found

        return stripeCharge.Id;
    }
```

If I POST AJAX call on POSTMAN, it shows

> **unexpected 's' in JSON**.

What it means in general, and in this case specifically?

Comment: It looks like postman (or the system generating that message) tries to interpret the response text as JSON and encounteres an 's' where it didn't expect it. What *is* the response text? And who gives that message - postman or stripe?

Comment: stripe simply returns Payment failed. Postman gives *this* message.

Comment: So, what *is* that response body exactly? Or maybe, what is the value of that `_ajax.Data`? Don't you need quotes around the stringified token?

Comment: `_ajax.Data` is simply a token: alphanumeric key. And I think quotes are not required if stringify is done.

Comment: @Vikrant, you are returning a string here and then the headers might be saying `application/json` and that is why the issue occurs. There is a `code` button which will show you sample code for curl as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FQYO.png. Do that an add a `-v` after `curl` to enabled verbose mode. Then execute that command in terminal and share the output of the same in your question

Comment: In the Response panel of Postman, try to switch to **Raw** or **Preview**.
You are probably in the **Pretty** mode using the **JSON** option and the response you get from Stripe is not a valid JSON and it is starting with an 's'.
I would also try this in your code: `_ajax.Data = "{ \"token\": \"" + token + "\"}";`

Comment: @tehCivilian, I tried that as well. Got no change in response!

Comment: @Vikrant then probably your method expects json but you don't have valid one - your key in the code starts with 's', are you sure you are managing your data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line

`_ajax.Data = "{token:" + JSON.stringify(token) + "}";`

You should use

```
var token = '"Your token with S goes here"';
_ajax.Data = "{token:" + JSON.stringify(token) + "}";
```

because only token is not valid json and you are trying to parse it

See the [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791718/json-parse-unexpected-token-s)